# Excluding Android specific assets from iOS build in Titanium?

Tags: build, package, titanium, assets

I have one code base that creates Android and iOS versions, in Titanium. I want to exclude Android specific images from my iOS build, to keep the package as lean as possible.

Besides manually moving assets out of the app folder prior to doing a build, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good resource for you.  I'll admit I knew it was in there and it took me a while to find it.

Platform-specific resources

Titanium gives you various ways to include platform-specific resources, like images, stylesheets, and scripts, in your project. Titanium uses an "overrides" system to make it easy to use platform-specific resources. Any file in the platform-specific Resources directories (Resources/android, Resources/iphone, or Resources/mobileweb) will override, or be used in place of, those in the Resources directory. You don't have to use any special notation in your code to specify that these files should be used.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Supporting_Multiple_Platforms_in_a_Single_Codebase

This is just a snippet of the information, there is more in the docs.

Comment: Yeah I wondered about just using that folder... it just means I'll have to add extra styles in my .tss files (because right now, all the various Android sizes are automatically getting swapped in).

Comment: I don't recall if it states it in that documentation clearly, but I believe you can change entire JS files out as well.  Let's say you have Android specific code for your home screen.  Home.js may be sitting in a screens folder.  In your Android specific folder, you could even have android/screens/home.js and during compile it will use the Android version of the home.js file rather than the one in screens/home.js.  I haven't used that too much, but perhaps a better choice than mixing in lots of Ti.Platform checks.